# Python cyclic import unexpected behavior

Tags: python-import, python-3.6, circular-dependency, cyclic-reference

I have discovered something unexpected when playing with cyclic imports. I have two files in the same directory:

`a.py`

```
import b
print("hello from a")
```

`b.py`

```
import a
print("hello from b")
```

Running either `python3 a.py` and `python3 b.py` does not result in a cyclic import related error. I know that the first imported module is imported under the name `__main__`, but I still do not understand this behavior. For example, running `python3 a.py` or `python -m a` produces the following output:

```
hi from a
hi from b
hi from a
```

<s>Looking at the output of `print(sys.modules.keys())`, I can see that both modules are somehow already imported when checking it, even when importing the `sys` module as the first thing in one of the modules.</s>
I did not use `sys.modules` properly before answering my own question.

<s>This does not happen if neither of the cyclic imported modules is the `__main__` module. My Python version is `Python 3.6.3` on `Ubuntu 17.10`.</s>
It still happens, but there is a visible error only if there is actually something you use from one of the cyclically imported modules.

See my own answer for clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The answer to my question

I have discovered the answer. I will try to sketch an explanation:

Executing `python3 a.py` imports the module in file `a.py` as `__main__`:

- `import b` in module `__main__`:

  - `import a` in module `b` -> Imports the module in file `a.py` as `a`
  - `import b` in module `a` -> Nothing happens, **already imported** that module
  - `print('hello from a')` in `a.py` (executing module `a`)
  - `import a` in module `b` finished
- `print('hello from b')` in `b.py` (executing module `b`)
- `import b` in module `__main__` finished
- `print('hello from a')` in `a.py`(executing module `__main__`)

The problem is that there is no cyclic import error per se. A module is imported only once, and after that, other imports of the same module can be seen as no-ops.

This operation can be seen as adding a key to the `sys.modules` dictionary corresponding to the name of the imported module and then setting attributes on the module object associated with that key as it gets executed. So if the key is already present in the dictionary (on a second import of the same module), nothing happens on the second import. The **already imported** above means already present in the `sys.modules` dictionary. This reflects the procedural nature of Python (being originally implemented in C) and the fact that anything in Python is an object.

## The lurking problem

In order to show the fact that the problem associated with cyclic imports is still present, let's add a function to module `b` and try to use it from module `a`.

`a.py`

```
import b

b.f()
```

`b.py`

```
import a

def f():
    print('hello from b.f()')
```

Executing now `python a.py` imports the module in file `a.py` as `__main__`:

- `import b` in module `__main__`:

  - `import a` in module `b` -> Imports the module in file `a.py` as `a`
  - `import b` in module `a` -> Nothing happens, **already imported** that module
  - `b.f()` -> `AttributeError: module 'b' has no attribute 'f'`

**Note**: The line `b.f()` can be further simplified to `b.f` and the error will still occur. This is because `b.f()` first accesses the attribute `f` of module object `b`, which happens to be a function object, and then tries to call it. I wanted to point out again the object oriented nature of Python.

## The `from ... import ...` statement

It is interesting to mention that using the `from ... import ...` form gives another error, even though the reason is the same:

`a.py`

```
from b import f

f()
```

`b.py`

```
import a

def f():
    printf('hello from b.f()')
```

Executing `python a.py` imports the module in file `a.py` as `__main__`:

- `from b import f` in module `__main__` actually **imports** the whole module (adds it to `sys.modules` and executes its body), but binds only the name `f` in the current module namespace:

  - `import a` in module `b` -> Imports the module in file `a.py` as `a`
  - `from b import f` in module `a` -> `ImportError: cannot import name f` (because the first execution of `from b import f` did not get to see the definition of the function object `f` in module `b`)

In this last case, the `from ... import ...` itself fails with an error because the interpreter knows earlier in time that you are trying to access something in that module which does not exist. Compare it to the first `AttributeError`, where the program did not see any problem until it tried to access attribute `f` (in the expression `b.f`).

## The double execution problem of the code in the **main** module

When importing the module in the file used to start the program (imported as `__main__` first) from another module, the code in that module gets executed twice and any side effects in that module execution will happen twice too. This is why it is not recommended to import the main module of the program again in other modules.

## Using `sys.modules` to confirm my conclusions above

I will show how checking the contents of `sys.modules` can clarify this problem:

`a.py`

```
import sys

assert '__main__' in sys.modules.keys()
print(f'{__name__}:')
print('\ta imported:', 'a' in sys.modules.keys())
print('\tb imported:', 'b' in sys.modules.keys())

import b

b.f()
```

`b.py`

```
import sys

assert '__main__' in sys.modules.keys()
print(f'{__name__}:')
print('\ta imported:', 'a' in sys.modules.keys())
print('\tb imported:', 'b' in sys.modules.keys())

import a

assert False  # Control flow never gets here

def f():
    print('hi from b.f()')
```

The output of `python3 a.py`:

```
__main__:
    a imported: False
    b imported: False
b:
    a imported: False
    b imported: True
a:
    a imported: True
    b imported: True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 8, in <module>
    import b
  File "/home/andrei/PycharmProjects/untitled/b.py", line 8, in <module>
    import a
  File "/home/andrei/PycharmProjects/untitled/a.py", line 10, in <module>
    b.f()
AttributeError: module 'b' has no attribute 'f'
```